# Node.js locally on port 3000, without specifying port

Tags: node.js, webserver

I have a local instance of a node.js app and setup my hosts file to give a domain name.  I want to be able to use a wildcard certificate I have.  However, this doesn't work because I still have to specify the port number.

Is it possible to run this locally, without specifying the port?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either run it on port 80 or set up a reverse proxy on port 80 to send the appropriate requests to port 3000.

Comment: He talks about a certificate so I assume he wants to use SSL. In this case you need to bind to port 443 or have a proxy running on this port.